# Killing a process but it doesn't close

Tags: process, kill

I wrote a C program that creates a process that opens a `.txt` file and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, it will close the process and print out a message but I'm having a huge problem. The process I created when I kill it doesn't close:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t child_id;

void ctrl_C(int sig){
    kill(child_id, 9);
    printf("\nYou pressed Ctrl + C,Good Bye \n");

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    kill(child_id, SIGINT);
}



int main(){
    printf("I am Programmer \n");
    child_id = fork();
    if (child_id == 0) {
        execlp("gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal", "--", "vi", "abcd.txt", NULL);
        return 255;
    }
    signal(SIGINT,ctrl_C);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Od7t.png)

Comment: The are two `child_id` variables: one local to `main` and one global. Remove the local one.

Comment: same it doesn't close ( changed "pid_t child_id = fork();" to "child_id = fork()" )

Comment: Your screenshot shows your program didn't catch the signal from ctrl/C as intended, but was killed by it. So it didn't get a chance to kill the child process, which explains why the child process didn't close.

Answer (score 0):

The process remains in the process table until you call `wait()` in the parent process (this is called "zombie state") or until that parent process exits as well, in which case it is reparented to systemd (formerly init) which does that `wait()` for such orphaned processes.

A zombie process has actually died, but its process table entry contains performance statistics and will stick around until the parent process has collected them with wait().  You can spot these with ps -eO stat and look for things with a Z in the stat column.  Zombie processes are not using any system resources except for the process table slot.

Comment: so i need to add else{ wait() }; am i right?

Comment: You need to read the man page of wait(2) and understand it and then add it to the right place of your program. Reading docs is important. ;-)